# Calling a method in Ruby with optional parameters, regardless of position in parameters list, and setting to hash

Tags: ruby, parameters, block

I have a class method, call it PetSearch.  I want to initialize a search with options via a class variable, @@options.  I can pass in either an array or a hash.  Chose array as such:

```
def self.init_options(options=['dog', 94123, 'Young', 'F'])  
  @@options[:animal] = options[0]  
  @@options[:location] = options[1]  
  @@options[:age] = options[2]
  @@options[:sex] = options[3]
end
```

However, I want to be able to pass in options like:

```
def self.init_options(dog, Young)
   @@options[:dog] = dog
   @@options[:age] = Young
end
```

Notice that I would like to pass in a non-string "variable" like dog - not 'dog', and I am passing in the variables indiscriminately without regard to order.  I'm assuming there's a meta-programming block/proc/etc. sort of way to do this, but I am still learning how to harness that power.  Can someone help me out?  I will receive my undying gratitude and major up-votes.

Comment: Any reason you can't use the typical Ruby method of options hash? Define `def self.init_options(options = {})
  @@options = options
end` And call it as `init_options( {dog: dog, age: Young} )`?

Comment: I want to make it easy for a user to pass in arguments without the need for {:animal => 'dog', :age => 'Young}.  It's too verbose.  It seems more logical for someone to go pass in (dog, young, 94123). I can do that with setting a variable to nil, but then I would have to pass in a nil variable if I skipped an optional parameter ('dog', 94123,nil,'F').  I don't like that nil.  I also don't like passing in quotes to define  a string.  Maybe I'm just creating a "wish list" item that doesn't exist.

Comment: The issue is that you need a way for the method to distinguish which parameters are being passed. That implies either positional identification (e.g., array or discrete params) or a hash. You could use optional parameters, but then specifying the 4th means you must specify something for the first three. What version of Ruby are you on? Hashes in version beyond 1.9 are less verbose (per my example).

Comment: Yeah, I had it as a hash structure, but I felt like writing the params without the keys, hence the array (where I know the order).  I'm on 2.0.0; so yes, I know I can do the `age: 'young'` version of writing hashes.  However, I'm stuck in the old mentality where "it just doesn't feel right" without the hash rocket.  So you're saying I'm kind of stuck in the hash world? No way to do what I want to do as per the question? I recognize that what I'm looking to do is unconventional - just trying to see if I can make my users' lives easier.

Comment: I'm saying you have options (array, hash, or discrete parameters) but they all have their issues relative to what you are asking for, which is a method that can magically tell which parameters you're setting and be able to pass them arbitrarily. There would have to be some kind of unique tag on each parameter to tell the method which one it's dealing with. That's basically what a hash does (with a key) or an array does (via array index), or discrete parameters do (via position). Although a hash is a little verbose, it's very clear so that would be my personal pick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would never recommend doing this, and it doesn't really make sense: most of the ways you would collect user input would be as strings (e.g., script arguments, form values, etc.).

You can abuse `method_missing` and `const_missing` to pass in your arguments as non-strings.

So in your class or module you could have something like:

```
def self.init_options(*args)
  @@options[:dog] = args.grep(/[Dd]og|etc|etc/).first
  @@options[:age] = args.grep(/[Oo]ld|[Yy]oung/).first
end

def self.options
  @@options
end
```

And then, in the context where your user is doing the "initializing":

```
def method_missing(m)
  m.to_s
end

def Object.const_missing(c)
  c.to_s
end

Testmm.init_options(dog, Young)
puts Testmm.options.inspect
#=> {:dog=>"dog", :age=>"Young"}
```

Not sure if that is the behavior you are looking for, but it sounds like it. Also note that this won't work in `IRB`, but I've confirmed that it works as a script.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It does work in a script, but it's a no-go via irb as you said. Creative solution to a weird "feature request."   Since my question is kind of wonky, I'm going to redact the non-string parameter element and stick with strings.  I like your solution to the arguments dilemma as well.  That solves the major issue associated with my problem.  Thanks very much.